# budget allocation in research grant applications

Tags: funding

How to find about info about proportions of different categories in budget in grant applications? For instance, how much put in travel, how much put in RA fees etc.

Comment: That will depend on the individual project.

Comment: Schools often have a "proposal development teams/depts.". You send them a list of the items/RA/equipment etc., and they put together a budget. This is usually an iterative process.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from asking your institution's research support unit (if there is one) as suggested in other answers, try to get in touch with colleagues with grants similar to yours (in terms of grant call, scale of the funding and scientific area) and see if they can show you their budget. In my experience when I was new to grant requests, this was the single most helpful thing that helped me tune my budget.

Comment: but some school research support units just give official answers according to rules, without giving useful individual feedback. afterwards, they reject our internal grant applications saying that the budget isn't reasonable

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky your University has a research support unit, which you tell what you need and they create the budget for you, then tell you what parts of that budget that funding agency has and has not funded in the pasted, what items you might have forgotten etc. After some back and forth you get the final budget.

Comment: but some school research support units just give official answers according to rules, without giving useful individual feedback. afterwards, they reject our internal grant applications saying that the budget isn't reasonable